# Is there a way to set a param in a class instance with an implicit conversion, like an operator in c#?

Tags: c#

So lets say i have this class:

```
public class LogLine
{ 
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string this[object o] { get => Text; set => Text = value; }
}
```

And then I have this other one:

```
public class Logger 
{
    
    public LogLine WriteLine(string _text, LogLine v)
    {
        LogLine obj = v;
    
        obj[null] = _text;

        return obj;
    }

}
```

And everything works as inteded, but I would like to do something like

> obj = _text;

instead of

> obj[null] = _text;

So the final question would be: Is there a way to do that?

I know I could always do

> obj.Text = _text;

So I also would like to know if I am just asking about something like bad practice or so. I'm learning n.n'

Comment: What's the purpose of `obj[null]` and `obj.Text`? It's not really clear what those represent

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) from `string` to `LogLine`:

```
public class LogLine
{ 
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator LogLine(string input)
    {
        return new LogLine{ Text = input };
    }
}
```

Now this is allowed:

```
obj = _text;
```